# Extrai dados do um site e joga na sua aplicação web Flask

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

Qual é módulo que poderia usar em flask para obter dados de uma API e joga na minha aplicação web na parte do HTML

Answer (score 0):

Tem uma lib chamada requests (pip install requests), que é usada para fazer requisições. No exemplo abaixo eu faço um get e retiro o json da resposta da requisição.

```
from requests import get

url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
response = get(url)
user = response.json()
```